# Removing ' ' from sql query and stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which a column named data is of type varbinary . If I do a simple query

`select * from tab where data = 1` then it works but if I do `select * from tab where data = '1'` then it does not return any row. The issue comes when I create a stored proc to retrieve data from this table and it converts the query and adds ' ' in the parameter when querying and so I am not able to retrieve any data. Can some one please tell me how to get around this issue.

```
Parameters
 @ID   INT = NULL  
,@Data    varchar(100)  = NULL 

CREATE TABLE #Results (      
         ID     INT      
        ,Data varchar(100)  

      )  

BEGIN    
    INSERT #Results (
         ID 
        ,Data 

        )  
    SELECT 
               SK.ID              
              ,SK.Data  

    FROM    dbo.tab SK
    where SK.ID =  @ID And SK.data = @data 

 END  

  SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(*)    
     FROM #Results 

 SELECT @TotalRows TotalRows
```

Now from the code when I execute this statement

```
  oReader = ExecuteReader(oConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Proc", New SqlParameter("@ID", Request.ID), _
                                                                                              New SqlParameter("@Data", Request.Data))
```

I see in SQL Profiler that it runs the query as 'data' 
which does not return any rows

Thanks

Comment: Fix the stored procedure.

Comment: provide your query please!!

Comment: What is the data type of the data field from table tab?

Comment: show your sp and the invocation to your sp...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said that you have written an SP, I think the inpput parameter is specified as NVARCHAR or VARCHAR

Below is one way of doing but i'm guessing that the column called data will only have integer values in the first solution.

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(5) 
SET @X = '1 '
SELECT CAST(@X AS INT)
```

The above is only if the  Data column specified above is Integer.

**If the same is string (VARCHAR)** you can write a User defined function to do the same.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string VARCHAR(8000))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
  BEGIN
     RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
  END


 SELECT dbo.TRIM('1 ')
```

I hope the above was useful, I did get the idea rather copied the function from here 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/24/sql-server-trim-function-udf-trim/